# generating select with options for html with array data javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

I want to generate select and options for my project dynamically with array data
here I attached what I want and what is the data I have this is data

[image]
This is the options I want

[image]]

please help to get solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+select+options+from+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: but I need option value should be like that what I attached in this question
eg: you can see 17 has value 14 so step 17 has in html its value should be 14

Comment: @GowthamS I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trickier than it looked

You do not have an array but an object. I renamed it and we can use the Object.entries(stepLabelObject) to loop or reduce.

Filter and map does not work well here.

Reduce

```js
const stepLabelObject = { 0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5", 6: "6", 7: "7", 8: "8", 9: "", 10:"9", 11: "10", 13: "11", 14: "12", 15: "13", 16: "", 17: "14", 18: "15", 19: "", 20: "16", 21: "17", 22: "", 23: "", 24: "18", 27: "", 28: "", 29: "", 30: "", 31: "", 32: "19", 33: "", 34: "", 35: "", 36: "", 37: "", 38: "", 39: "", 40: "20" };

const stepsDropDown = e => { console.log(e.target.value) };
let cnt = 0;
const options = Object.entries(stepLabelObject).reduce((acc,[key,val]) => {
  if (val !== "") acc.push(`<option value="${key}">step : ${++cnt}</option>`);
  return acc;
});
const sel = document.getElementById('stepDropDown');
sel.innerHTML = options.join('');
sel.addEventListener('change',stepsDropDown);
```

```html
<select id="stepDropDown"></select>
```

Comment: yes like this but in html steps will be 1 to 20 and its value whould be that 40

Comment: Ok, from 1 - 20  - do do I ignore step 0 or add a step 0?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Input data is an `object` not an `array` and you can iterate over the object keys with the help of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method and then loop over it to create the options dynamically.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let stepLabelObject = {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5"};

Object.keys(stepLabelObject).forEach(key => {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = key;
  option.text = `Step : ${key}`;
  document.getElementById('stepdropdown').appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<select id="stepdropdown" onChange="stepsDropdown()"></select>
```